# Want to understand Big O by graph

Tags: asymptotics

$f(n) = 3n+3$ ;
$f(n) = O(n)$
By definition :
$3n+3 \leq c_1.n$
By dividing both side by $n$
$3+\frac{3}{n} \leq c_1$
means we are getting constant range for $c_1$ for any $n$. Again it shows $c_1$'s value must be   greater than $3$ at any cost.
e.g. if we take $c_1$'s value 3.5 so $n$'s value will be $6$.
Now if we plot graph ( Because I want to learn this concept by understanding graph )
$c_1.g(n)$ graph goes below of $f(n)$ graph. I have taken following values for both functions :
$f(n)=3n+3$

$
\begin{matrix}
n & f(n)\\
1 & 6\\
2 & 9\\
3 & 12\\
-2 & -3
\end{matrix}
$

for $g(n) = 3.5n$
$
\begin{matrix}
n & g(n)\\
1 & 3.5\\
2 & 7\\
3 & 10.5\\
-2 & -7
\end{matrix}
$

If we plot graph by these values it doesn't bind $f(n)$ i.e. $3n+3$ above by the value of $g(n)$ i.e. $3.5n$
Can anyone explain me this concept by graph ?

Comment: All that matters is the **asymptotic** behaviour as n goes to infinity.

Comment: Can you try to clean up the formatting of your question and make it a bit more obvious what you're asking?

Comment: To elaborate on @OliCharlesworth, since `n` is going to infinity, looking at `n=-2` makes no sense; you need to look at extremely large `n`.  For example, you find that in your example, you need `n` to be at least 6.  But the largest `n` you try is 3, and then you wonder why it doesn't work.

Comment: [Don't.](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/857/how-to-fool-the-plot-inspection-heuristic).

Comment: 1. [Don't.](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/857/how-to-fool-the-plot-inspection-heuristic) 2. See [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/57/how-does-one-know-which-notation-of-time-complexity-analysis-to-use).

Answer (score 3):

Here are a picture and some description:

> The formal definitions associated with the Big Oh notation are as
> follows:
>
> • f (n)= O (g (n)) means c · g (n)isan upper bound on f (n).
> Thus there exists some constant c such thatf (n) is always ≤ c · g
> (n), for large enoughn (i.e. , n ≥ n<sub>0</sub> for some constant n0 ).
>
> • f(n)=Ω(g (n)) means c · g (n) is a lower bound onf (n). Thus there exists
> some constant c such that f (n) is always ≥ c · g (n), for all n ≥ n<sub>0</sub>.
>
> • f (n)=Θ(g (n)) means c<sub>1</sub> · g (n) is an upper bound on f(n) and c<sub>2</sub>
> ·g(n) is a lower bound on f (n), for all n ≥ n<sub>0</sub> . Thus there exist
> constants c<sub>1</sub> and c<sub>2</sub> such that f(n) ≤ c<sub>1</sub> · g(n) and f(n) ≥ c<sub>2</sub> · g
> (n). This means that g(n) provides a nice, tight bound on f(n).
> [image]

You can find more details in the Chapter 2 of The Algorithm Design Manual,Steven S. Skiena.

Comment: This is all correct (and useful if you're looking for a basic understanding of the concept), but it isn't too difficult to come up with examples (e.g., `log[log[x]]`, `e^{x/1000}`) where `n0` is so big that you won't find it unless you already know the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The big $O$ notation describes the limiting behavior of a function. That mean the property you are looking for is true for $n$ large enough.

$g(n)$ may be smaller than $f(n)$ for small $n$ but as $n$ goes to the infinite $g(n)$ will at some point always be greater than $f(n)$.

What the big $O$ notation look like on a graph is: if you look at the two right end of both function $f(n)$ is lower than $g(n)$. But it's hard to look at infinity with a graph...

Answer (score 2):

From [introduction to the design and analysis of algorithms](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132316811):

a function $t(n)$ is $O(g(n))$ if $t(n)$ is bounded above by some constant multiple of $g(n)$ for all large $n$.

So, $t(n) \le cg(n) \quad \text{for all $n>n_o$}$

[image: big O]

This image is from [here](http://www2.hawaii.edu/~suthers/courses/ics311f12/Notes/Topic-03.html).

Edit: I meant to say that the referenced book, as well as the webpage have graphical explanations for Oh, Omega, and Theta notation.