# Why is log(n/p) asymptotically less than log(n)/log(p)

Tags: asymptotics

I'm trying to figure out which is better asymptotic complexity, $O(\log{\frac{n}{p}})$ or $O\left(\frac{\log{n}}{\log{p}}\right)$. $p$ is the amount of parallelism (i.e. number of cores), and $n$ is the problem size. When I plot them in Grapher.app with any constant value for $p$, the first looks better:

[image]

But when I try to work out the math it doesn't seem right:

$$
O(\log{\frac{n}{p}}) = O(\log{n} - \log{p})
$$

$O\left(\frac{\log{n}}{\log{p}}\right)$ seems like a better bound than the above since it divides by $\log{p}$ instead of just subtracting it. What am I missing?

Comment: "Better complexity" - you can't see that from that plot, Landau notation hides constant factors and lower order terms.

Comment: i was incorrect in saying "p is a fixed constant." i'm trying to characterize asymptotic behavior for parallel algorithms, so p is the number of cores. the plot is meant to be an example with p=8. i'll correct the wording.

Comment: Try e.g. $p = \sqrt{n}$ and see what happens.

Comment: Your question is answered by combining [this](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/857/how-to-fool-the-plot-inspection-heuristic) and [this](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/824/sorting-functions-by-asymptotic-growth).

Comment: @JukkaSuomela I want that computer!

Answer (score 10):

I assume that $p > 1$ (which is equivalent to $\log p > 0$, otherwise we have negative-valued functions which are meaningless as complexity measures.

**For a given $p$**,  $O\left(\frac{\log n}{\log p}\right) = O(\log n)$ since big oh isn't affected by multiplication by a positive constant.
$\log \frac{n}{p} = \log n - \log p$. Since $\log p = o(\log n)$, $O\left(\log \frac{n}{p}\right) = O(\log n)$.

So up to big-oh complexity (or big-theta, for the same reasons), these two classes are the same.

Your diagram doesn't show a visual difference: you need to bring the two curves to the same scale. One is $a \log n$ for some constant $a > 0$, the other is $\log n + b$ for some constant $b$.

If you want to study the variation in $p$, then $O$ or $\Theta$ with respect to the variable $n$ are not good ways of modeling the complexity of your problem. You need more precise approximations that treat multiplicative constants as relevant. The complexity in $p$ is probably relevant to your problem, and is very different. I'm not familiar enouhg with parallelism to know whether it's the right measure to use here, this could warrant a separate question (with more information about what you're modeling). You're going to need express the complexity in terms of $n$ and $p$, and look at how *the variation in $p$* (not the complexity itself) behaves for large $n$.