# Proof of Asymptotic Fact

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

I was trying to prove the next exercise [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qj3S4.png)

[image]

It's not look so hard, but with some tries, I couldn't find out a way to show it, I was supposed wrong assumptions.

To convince myself if that relation really happened, I use Mathematica to plot some a range.

[image]

Do you have some ideas?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qj3S4.png) Ian Parberry and William Gasarch. Problems on algorithms, volume 50. 2 edition, 2002.

Comment: Try using [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

Comment: The techniques you need are explained [in our reference post](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/824/sorting-functions-by-asymptotic-growth). Note also that [plots can be deceiving](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/857/how-to-fool-the-plot-inspection-heuristic).