# Is this time complexity quasi-polynomial?

Tags: terminology, asymptotics, landau-notation

I have been working in the time analysis for an algorithm and finally I got a curve that fits:

$O(2^{(\log_2(N)^{2.01})})$

N is the number of elements.

I'm right to say the above time complexity is quasi-polynomial?

Comment: What "elements"? That is crucial here. (Also, don't use "time complexity"; you have an asymptotic upper bound.)

Comment: Oh, I just saw this: "I got a curve that fits" -- oh no, [don't do that](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/857/how-to-fool-the-plot-inspection-heuristic)! What you are doing is not analysis but fortune-telling. If you want to learn about "real" algorithm analysis, you may want to head over to our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/844/98) on the matter.

Comment: @Raphael log2 = log (base 2) (i.e. Log2(32) = 5 ), N = input size (number of input elements).

Comment: @Raphael I was focusing to double check the resultant time complexity. There is no curve that fits" the result is an asymptotic worst case analysis for an algorithm

Comment: "input size" and "number of input elements" is *not* necessarily the same. Which size does each element have? Are they numbers?

Comment: Yes, they are numbers and Input Length and Size of each element are equal (N=P) being N the number of input elements and P the number of bits required to represent 
each input element, so for instance:

SET= {1,22,333,4444,55555,666666,7777777,10170128,10596586,10833720,11300828,12152672,16453700,18839720,19496780,22409892,2,493424,26606324,26985764,30017152,30169256,30345762,30371136,30561184,31495936}

N = 25 and P = 25, Log2(Max(Set)) = 25, or maybe I can use LOG2(SUM(SET)) = 29.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quasi-polynomial means different things to different people, but in many contexts it means a running time of the form $O(2^{O(\log^{O(1)} N)})$, to which your example conforms.

Comment: Is $N$ for you the size of the input (encoding), or what is it?

Comment: $N$ is always the size of the input, unless stated otherwise.

Comment: I only wish that were true. That said, note that the OP binds $N$ to be the "number of elements".