# How can you prove 3^n is not O(n^2)?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, asymptotics

I can obviously tell by inspection that it is not true but I cannot figure out how to prove it with witnesses (C and k). Thanks!

Comment: Hint: try to prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n^2}{3^n}=0$.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: "I can obviously tell by inspection that it is not true" -- [I don't think you can](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/857/how-to-fool-the-plot-inspection-heuristic).

Answer (score -1):

Let's assume that $3^n = O(n^2)$.

This would by definition mean that there are real positive numbers $a$ and $b$ such that for any sufficiently large $n$ (or to say as $lim_{n \to +\infty}$):

$ an^2 \leq 3^n \leq bn^2 $

Dividing everything by $3^n$ we get:

$ a\frac{n^2}{3^n} \leq 1 \leq b\frac{n^2}{3^n}$

And since if we let $lim_{n \to +\infty}$ we get a contradiction:

$ 0 \leq 1 \leq 0 $

Hence inital statement is false and $ 3^n \neq O(n^2) $

Comment: This is wrong. $O$ does *not* imply such lower bounds. Also, I don't think your double-limit (you use an inequality that only holds sometimes, then manipulate it as if it holds everywhere, then let $n\to\infty$) is very rigorous.

Comment: @itsRAWRtime007: $O$ notation only establishes upper bounds (not lower). The reasoning should go as follows: $3^n \neq O(n^2)$ because there exist some constant $c$ (for example, $c=1$) such that $3^n > c \cdot n^2$ for all $n  \geq 0$.

Comment: Sorry mixed it up with $\theta$. What I gave above is proof for theta> I think you can just use one side of the inequalities for $O$

Comment: Also it wasn't meant to be truly rigorous. Then we should define what does it mean "to have sufficiently large n". Just wanted to give a general idea of the proof. But if n is chosen such that both sides of inequality are satisfied (e.g taking the max $n_0$) then i think we can work it out in this double inequality notation.