# Comparing $\log^\alpha n$ with $n^\beta$

Tags: asymptotics

I'm trying to solve a recurrence using the master method:

$T(n) = 10*T(n/3) + n^2\log^5n$

I set up the comparison

$n^2\log^5n$ and $n^{\log_3 10}$

and reduced them to:

$\log^5 n$ and $n^{\log_3(10/9)}$

I'm struggling to understand how these functions compare asymptotically.

From one side I understand that in general polynomials grow slower than logarithms, as written in a similar question here: [Sorting functions by asymptotic growth](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/824/sorting-functions-by-asymptotic-growth).

However, I graphed both of the functions using a graphing calculator and it appeared that the logarithmic function grew faster than the polynomial, even at large n.

Basically, is it really true that $(\log n)^{\alpha} = o(n^\beta)$ for all $\alpha,\beta>0$? If it is, how would you go about rigorously proving it one way or the other?

Comment: Where was that written in the linked question? ​ ​

Comment: It's like the 9th bullet on Raphaels answer

Comment: I only see 8 bullets in that answer. ​ ​

Comment: Hmmm I'm on my phone so that might be affecting how I view it. It's right after "It is also useful to keep a pool of basic relations you prove once and use often, such as:"

Comment: The thing just after that is _the opposite_ of what you wrote. ​ ​

Comment: That answer is the best you will do; that's why we call it *reference* question. Plots are not a suitable tool here; neither do they prove anything, nor should they make you uncertain (for the same reasons). See also [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/857/how-to-fool-the-plot-inspection-heuristic).

Comment: How so? Maybe I don't fully understand the notation, but what I'm trying to say is that $n^\beta$ is a tight asymptotic upper bound for the logarithmic function

Comment: you wrote "in general polynomials grow slower than logarithms" but the referenced answer states the opposite: "logarithms grow slower than polynomials". So it is really true that $(\log n)^{\alpha} = o(n^\beta)$ and your graphic calculator is misleading you.

Comment: and your question is "How to proof that $(\log n)^{\alpha} = o(n^\beta)$"?

Comment: Look at CLRS 3ed page 57 for a proof.