# Do exponents have higher time complexity than factorials?

Tags: asymptotics

My professor said exponentials will always have higher time complexity compared to polynomials. My question is, do exponentials also have higher time complexity than factorials?

I plotted a chart in Matlab to check it myself.

When range of x is small, from 1 to 10, I get the following chart,

```
%Matlab script
x  = [1 : 10];
y1 = factorial(x);
y2 = exp(x);

plot(x', [y1',y2']);
title("N! vs e^N");
legend("O(n!)", "O(e^n)");
```

[image]
Here factorial is clearly beating exponential.

But when I bump the range of x from 1 to 1000, I get the following chart,

```
x  = [1 : 1000];
```

[image]

Here exponential is clearly beating factorial.

So, can I say conclusively that exponentials will always have higher time complexity than both factorials and polynomials?

-

Comment: Plot is not an oracle, based on two pictures, no, you cannot say that. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: Note that your question has nothing to do with either algorithms or time complexity.

Comment: Have you *read* the [material linked for you](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/824/sorting-functions-by-asymptotic-growth)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact $e^n$ is $o(n!)$. We could show it using the Stirling approximation by [taking limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation)
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\frac{e^n}{(\sqrt{2\pi n})(\frac{n}{e})^n}} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\frac{e^{2n}}{(\sqrt{2\pi n})n^n}} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}\frac{e^{2n}}{n^n}}$$

Since $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}} = 0$ we only need to calculate
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\left(\frac{e^2}{n}\right)^n}$$
The function $\frac{e^2}{n}$ decreases faster than any function $c^n$ where $0 < c < 1$ for sufficiently large $n$s (as $n$ goes to infinity), and so $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\left(\frac{e^2}{n}\right)^n} = 0$.

**Regarding Quazi Irfan's comments about Matlab graph**
I am not a Matlab user, but these are plots for $e^x$ and Stirling approximations of $n!$ using Wolfram script: `plot (1\sqrt(2*pi*x)*(x/e)^x) from 0 to 6, plot(e^x) from 0 to 6`
[image]

As you see $n!$ overtakes $e^n$ when $n=6$.

Comment: @fade2black So my deduction is wrong. The growth of factorial function would be greater than exponentials? - Did I interpret your answer correctly?

Comment: @QuaziIrfan n factorial eventualy grows faster than exp(n). In fact it is true for any constant base.

Comment: @fade2black I've added the Matlab script to show how I got my graph. Can you explain why in the graph, the n! curve didn't take over e^n? It looks the n! curve suddenly stopped growing at ~160.

Comment: That plot is useless; see [e.g. here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/16714/98). If you want to use plots to drive your work, plot the quotient and check whether it seems to converge. Log(-log) plots can also be useful when large functions are involved.

Comment: @fade2black`"I want to show at what point one function overtakes other one."` > This is correct. Our professor is asking us to plot 2 graphs for each pair of functions. One to show the crossing points, and another to show that for sufficiently large X one function clearly dwarfs another. I was having trouble plotting both of the graphs.

Comment: @QuaziIrfan then plot $\frac{e^n}{n!}$ and see, it should go to zero as $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: You can easily show that n! ≥ (exp(n))^2 for n ≥ 18.