# Determing Big Oh Of Given Data

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, big-o-notation

I'm trying to determine the big O time complexity of the following
[data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sStmD.png) where the first column is the input size, and the second column is the execution time in seconds. Where possible, I should determine the exponent of the dominant term and provide an estimate for the coefficient on the dominant term.

---

I made the following
[graph of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRRVJ.png) and a [log/log graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onTqC.png) to try and figure it out. At first I thought it might have been 1/n or something along those lines but as n gets quite large, the execution time increases again instead of asymptotically approaching a value.

The log graph having such a distinct pattern leads me to believe that the answer will lie there but I'm stuck as to where to go from here. Any help would be great.

Comment: Hi, welcome to CS.SE :) Some notes: (Asymptotic) running time is a property of an algorithm, not a "data set". Also, can you explain why the execution time _decreases_ with growing input size? This is very uncommon. A bit more information would probably help a lot here.

Comment: With existing information looks like it is more question of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_theory

Comment: Hi, interesting question. I'm just curious, why input size 1 has the largest execution time in your dataset?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  You can't infer big-O complexity from a finite set of data points, as big-O complexity is about asymptotics.  See, e.g., [How to fool the plot inspection heuristic?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/857/755).